# What does it mean to have a flat scope?

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

In Kapacitor [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/tick/introduction/), there is a sentence that reads:

> Each script has a flat scope and each variable in the scope can
>   reference a literal value, such as a string, an integer or a float
>   value, or a node instance with methods that can then be called.

I have never heard of a flat scope, what does that mean? I tried googling for that term but I cannot find anything that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Scopes in Kapacitor is similar to the scope in JS or PowerShell

References
[Scopes in PowerShell](https://www.howtogeek.com/203778/how-scopes-affect-powershell-scripts)
[Scope in JavaScript](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't see any mentions of a "flat" scope in that article?